# Remote SSH To Rasp Behind NAT Via Web

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io, raspberry-pi

I would like to implement access to a remote Raspberry which is behind a NAT/Firewall (dynamic IP) by using websockets and therefore a Web Client.

I was thinking to do it via `socket.io`. Raspbian and Web Client will subscribe to a common channel and then they will exchange ssh packets over that channel.

The difficult part is to convert `ssh` packet to ssh commands on Raspberry side.
Does anybody ever implemented this system?

Maybe something like [this](https://www.packtpub.com/books/content/making-simple-web-based-ssh-client-using-nodejs-and-socketio).

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to get around firewalls with ssh try tmate

Below are instructions how to use it for a remote setup

Needed:

- tmate
- a google account

`

```
#!/bin/bash
#if Internet connection 
if [[ $(ping -W 1 -c 1 8.8.8.8) == *", 0% packet loss,"*  ]];
then
   echo online;
   #if connection already exists 
   if [[ -S /tmp/tmate.sock ]];
   then
      echo "aready up"
   else
      tmate -S /tmp/tmate.sock new-session -d
   fi
   tmate -S /tmp/tmate.sock wait tmate-ready
   ssh=$(tmate -S /tmp/tmate.sock display -p '#{tmate_ssh}')
   ssh=$(sed 's~ssh ~~g' <<< $ssh)
   echo $ssh
   #sends ssh session to you
   curl "https://script.google.com/macro/s/{{ google script location }}/exec?id={{ unique id for raspberry pi }}&ssh=$ssh" > /dev/null
else
   #no Internet retry in 30 seconds 
   echo offline;
   sleep 30s
   bash {{ location of this script }}
fi
```

Have the above code on the raspberry pi with the users cron job set with `@reboot {{ user }} bash {{ location of script }}`

Login to google and go to http://script.google.com/ when there input this code

`

```
function doGet(e) {
  var id = e.parameter.id;
  var ssh = e.parameter.ssh;
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("{{ url of google spread sheet to dump data to }}").getActiveSheet();
  var lr = ss.getLastRow();
  var data = ss.getRange(1,1,lr,1).getValues();
  data = data.join("`").split("`");
  var loc = data.indexOf(id);
  if(loc != -1){
    ss.getRange(loc+1,2).setValue(ssh);
  }else{
    ss.appendRow([id,ssh]);
  }
}
```

Now on the google script under publish hit deploy as web app allow even anonymous and now you have your google script url.

Notes:

- Anything with {{ stuff }} is to be input by you
- If the raspberry pi reboots google will overwrite the old ssh location with the new one

All the stuff that is beyond tmate is just to reestablish a connection in case of losing power or needing to reboot